# Window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(url) returns 404 in ionic cordova using openwithios plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, wkwebview, ionic5

I am using cordova openwith-ios plugin, for sharing content to app , I am getting file url like this " file:///users/ path". When I try to load the image using Window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(url) It returns result as an url but gives 404( Resource has no content).

Comment: Same issue. I'am using iframe with local html file. When I check with the file plugin, it shows file. The file in the url resulting from convertFileSrc cannot be accessed. It gives 404 not found error. I couldn't find a way out.